# Why android toolbar height is cut?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, toolbar

I am new to the design pattern in latest android studio,the one with include
tag.I tried tweaking the files but ended up with cut toolbar.

**First Activity**

[image]

**first_activity.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">

   <include layout="@layout/app_bar_main" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
 tools:openDrawer="start">

 <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
 <FrameLayout
     android:id="@+id/frame_container"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" />

 <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
 <ListView
     android:id="@+id/main_nav_drawer"
     android:layout_width="240dp"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_gravity="start"
     android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
     android:divider="#888"
     android:dividerHeight="1dp"
     android:background="#fff"/>
     <!--android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"-->
      </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout> </LinearLayout>
```

Here's my app bar layout.

**app_bar_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".Activities.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530906/how-can-i-prevent-the-action-bar-from-being-cut-off?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530906/how-can-i-prevent-the-action-bar-from-being-cut-off?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change your toolbar XML this way:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>
```

Notice that `minHeight` disallows smaller sizes, and the `wrap_content` height now allows bigger toolbars.

Answer (score 5):

Remove fitSystemWindows Attribute from your theme

```
<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/main_nav_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="#888"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
        <!--android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"-->
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your app_bar_main layout as below -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.bits.ketan.geocoding.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am new to the design pattern in latest android studio,the one with
>   include tag.I tried tweaking the files but ended up with cut toolbar

I've had the similiar problem, it's working on real devices by the way.

And, Try to use

```
<include layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**inside your `DrawerLayout`** with that `Toolbar` inside the `AppBarLayout`

**Check the following links:**

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#DrawerLayout

> To add a navigation drawer, declare your user interface with a
>   **DrawerLayout object as the root view of your layout**. Inside the
>   DrawerLayout, add one view that contains the main content for the
>   screen (your primary layout when the drawer is hidden) and another
>   view that contains the contents of the navigation drawer.

And, use `NavigationView` instead of that `ListView`.

**A good example:**

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

     <!-- Your contents -->

     <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
         android:id="@+id/navigation"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_gravity="start"
         app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items" />
 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```